# Identity Certificates

Tags: ios, certificate, public-key, crt, pkcs#12

How can we identify if a certificate is 'Identity' Certificate.

I googled and found that PublicKey certificate are known as 'Identity Certificates'.

So .crt or .cer are Identity certificates

But at some places I see that .p12 are also referred to be Identity cert,

Can someone help me understand what is Identity certificate exactly.

Comment: .p12 is a way to store certificates and keys in a same container. Irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

see this for more information

[Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Tasks for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html) on developer.apple.com